# How to play/pause html5 video with spacebar

Tags: html, html5-video

How do you pause an html5 video with the spacebar using e.key? There's something off about the logic...

```
    <div class=modal-video id="v-5417">
    <div class=video-player>
                    <video id=v-5417-tape preload="none">
                        <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/anthem-od47.mp4">
                        <source type="video/webm" src="videos/anthem-od47.webm">
                    </video>
                    <div class="close-modal fade-control"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```js
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
            if ( e.keyCode === 32 ) {
                if (video.paused == true) {
                    // Play the video
                    video.play();
                }else{
                    if(video.play == true){
                    video.pause();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Shift or spacebar? The title says one and the question the other.

Comment: Whoops, spacebar. I corrected the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the changes to your javascript:

```html
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  var video = document.getElementById("vid");
  if (e.which == 32) {
    if (video.paused)
      video.play();
    else
      video.pause();
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work and gives me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paused' of null`

I had to change the "vid" id to the actual id as well, but nothing is working.

Comment: have you replaced the getElementById with your video id?

Comment: $(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var video = document.getElementById("v-5417");
    if (e.which == 32) {
      if (video.paused == true)
        video.play();
      else
        video.pause();
    }
  });

Comment: I think your video is missing quotes for video id.  <video id="v-5417-tape" preload="none">

Comment: Also, the id is "v-5417-tape" and not "v-5417"

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the scrolling of the web page to bottom.

```
var vid=document.getElementById('your_video_id_goes_here');

   document.body.onkeypress = function(e){
   if(e.which == 32){  
 // stops default behaviour of space bar. Stop page scrolling down
    e.preventDefault();  
    play_pause_video 
  }
} 

function play_pause_video() {
 if (vid.paused) 
 { 
  vid.play(); 
}
else 
{ 
 vid.pause(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('Video1')
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32) {
 if (videoPlayer.paused == false) {
            videoPlayer.pause();
            videoPlayer.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Play';
        } else {
            videoPlayer.play();
            videoPlayer.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Pause';
        }
  
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/website/js/playPause.js></script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Video</h1>
    <video id="Video1" autoplay="yes">
      <source src="videoName.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this should work.

```
// Press spacebar to Play/Pause.
    var body = $( 'body' );

    body.keypress( function ( e ) {
        if ( e.which == 32 ) {
            // Stop the jerk.
            e.preventDefault();

            // If video is paused.
            if ( theVideo.get(0).paused == true ) {
                theVideo.get(0).play();
            } else {
                theVideo.get(0).pause();
            }
        }
    }); // End keypress().
```